# What do subscript values indicate relative to polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

Fairly straight forward question, but in some cases I've identified some ambiguity. Consider the following function, *F(x)*:

$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$

and a second function, *G(x)*:

$b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+b_1x+b_0$

Straight away, it can be seen that this is the means of expressing a polynomial, and given this, the rational function $\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$, can be assembled. Now consider the following rule when graphing such a function:

1. If *m = n*, then $y=\frac{a_n}{b_m}$ is the horizontal asymptote

In this instance, what is meant by "*m = n*", because I always assumed subscript values refer to the position of a term in an expression, but if this were true, I don't understand how the horizontal asymptote can be inferred from this.

Comment: $m=n\,$ just means that the polynomials $\,F(x)\,$ and $\,G(x)\,$ have the same degree (there should be some assumption previously stated that $a_n \ne 0, b_m \ne 0$). The existence of the horizontal asymptote at $x \to \infty$ follows from $\require{cancel}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\frac{\bcancel{x^n}(a_n+ \cdots)}{\bcancel{x^m}(b_m +\cdots)} \to \frac{a_n}{b_m}\,$.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the clear and concise explanation. So i.e. if i had the polynomial $\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\frac{4x^2+6x+8}{2x^2+4x+4}$, would the horizontal asymptote then be at $\frac{4}{2} = 2$? @dxiv

Comment: Indeed, as shown in more detail in the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an add on to @dxiv comment, it can actually be shown that indeed if $a_n,b_m\neq0$, then $y=\frac {a_n}{b_m}$ is a horizontal asymptote to $P(x)=\frac {F(x)}{G(x)}$.

By definition, a horizontal asymptote exists if and only if $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}P(x)=k$ for some constant$k\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thus in general, we see:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}P(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0}{b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+b_1x+b_0}$$

Let's consider the case when $m=n$, then for $x\ne0$, we see:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}P(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0}{b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+b_1x+b_0}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+...+\frac {a_1}{x^{n-1}}+\frac {a_0}{x^n}}{b_n+\frac{b_{n-1}}{x}+...+\frac {b_1}{x^{n-1}}+\frac {b_0}{x^n}}=\frac {a_n}{b_n}$$

So indeed, regarding your above question in the comments, the horizontal asymptote is:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{4x^2+6x+8}{2x^2+4x+4}=\frac 42=2$$

Try considering what happens when $m>n$, or $m<n$.

Comment: When _m > n_, when simplified, _P(x)_ would become $\frac{1}{x^{m-n}}$, and hence the horizontal asymptote would be at _y = 0_, since the function obviously is not defined at _x = 0_, right? Similarly, when _m < n_, when simplified, _P(x)_ would become $\frac{x^{n-m}}{1}$, which would mean that there is no horizontal asymptote, and the graph assumes another shape. For example if _m = 2_, and _n = 4_, the result would be $P(x) = \frac{x^{4-2}}{1} = x^2$ meaning the graph would be a parabola. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that $\frac{1}{x^{m-n}}\ne0$, hence the horizontal asymptote is at _y = 0_

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There may also be coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ which will scale your function differently according to their values. Also, keep in mind their may be the existence of singularities or discontinuities within your function when you divide out a common factor. These are commonly referred to as "points of discontinuity" (with the addition of asymptotes) and are one of a few properties that make rational functions different than normal polynomial functions.